# Verify Scriptlets in ASPX files compile with MSbuild

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, build-automation, scriptlet

Sometimes after some refactoring occurs, and we produce a successful build, some legacy code using scriptlets fails to compile on runtime.  I would like it if there was a way that I can verify that scriptlets will compile using msbuild.

Is that what aspnet_compiler is for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that even the **aspnet_compiler.exe** tool will not complain about that. I'm not sure the best approach to avoid that.

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)